# Rails custom routing via Model String Key (instead of id)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to set up an application where I can route via a String key instead of an id attribute. To illustrate this, please consider the following:

I have a `class Foo` which inherits from the `ActiveRecord::Base` and is implemented as follows:

```
 class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :subject
```

**Subject** is a string type which exists in my database.

I have a controller which I implement as follows:

```
 class SubjectController < ApplicationController

 def index
   #snip
 end
```

As you can see, the SubjectController inherits from the ApplicationController.

Running `rake routes` gives me the standard (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) routes for my **subject**. This is the expected behavior and I understand this functionality.

I want to know how I can extend the `routes.rb` file so that I can use a string url in order to access a subject. For example:

Instead of typing in **localhost:3000/subject/1**, I would like this **/:id** to resolve when I type in the url: **localhost:3000/subject/grumpy-cat-says-hello**

1. What does this implementation look like?
2. How should I setup my `routes.rb` file to accommodate this?
3. How should I configure my application to allow for this type of implementation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always used https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id for this stuff.

If you prefer something simpler, this will do

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    [id, subject.parameterize].join("-")
  end
end
```

Then you can access your resource with: `localhost:3000/foos/1-grumpy-cat-says-hello`
Basically, since the name of the resource still starts with a number, it will be converted to a number by Rails and everything will work seamlessly.

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730) goes in much greater detail about this topic :)

Comment: Just installed the gem and am getting it all setup. Thanks a ton! Ultra fast response too!! Thanks, Ju Liu!